# Eclipse validate XML

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-2.2-froyo, eclipse-adt

I have be developing using the Android eclipse ADT for a while now. I have always been able to right click on any editor window that had an xml file open, and then hit "validate" to validate the xml. I just recently updated to the most recent version of the ADT 23.0.0. Now Validate has completely disappeard. I have gone into preferences -> XML -> xml validation, and have played with everything I could, but it still does not show up.

How can I get the validate option to show up again?

Thanks

EDIT: I noticed in my old version of eclipse under preferences a Validation section existed, in the new version it does not exist. eg Preferences->Validation

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> XML -> XML Validation -> set **no grammar specified** as warning or error

Comment: Thanks for reply. That didn't help though. I have gone through everything I could in that menu and nothing fixed it. I still have no xml validation option

Comment: did you try restore defaults option?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in forgetting that I had the eclipse web developer tools installed in my last eclipse install. This is what was missing. I find it much more convient to use these tools for xml.